# How to check which tables in DB (MYSQL) updated in last 1 hour / last 1 minute?

Tags: mysql, update

I have to create a xls datafeed for a website and I would like to know which tables are getting affected when I do a manual entry from CMS.

If i have installed fresh database and I'm doing first entry in it using CMS: I would like to know which tables got updated/appended in last 1 min in that DB.

It is somewhat similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated

But in my case I dont know which tables to check. I can check each and every table in the db using the solution posted in the question but I have a gut feeling that there is a better solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct answers I have to give by Storage Engine

## MyISAM

For all MyISAM tables, checking the last time a table was updated is quick and dirty

```
SET @IntervalMinutes = 2;
SET @IntervalSeconds = @IntervalMinutes * 60;
SET @DBtoCheck = DATABASE();
SELECT table_schema,table_name,update_time
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='MyISAM'
AND table_schema = @DBtoCheck
AND update_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL @IntervalSeconds SECOND)
ORDER BY update_time DESC A;
```

## InnoDB

I have some bad news: you cannot trust the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database because

- Transaction Behavior of InnoDB
- Location of the Data and Index Pages
- Heavy duty locking of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA when reading about an InnoDB table

In order to know the last update by some timestamp, you must have [`innodb_file_per_table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled. If not, all the data and index pages will sit inside ibdata1 (system tablespace). It would be anybody's guess when a table experienced an update.

You should first [cleanup the InnoDB Infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261).

Then, the easiest way to get the timestamp is to ask the OS for it

## EXAMPLE

Given this scenario

- [**datadir**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir) is `/var/lib/mysql`
- you want timetamp of `mydb.mytable`

Simply run this in the OS

```
TS_TAB=`ls -l --time-style="+%s" /var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd | awk '{print $6}'`
TS_NOW=`date +%s`
(( TS_DIFF = TS_NOW - TS_TAB ))
```

`TS_DIFF` will be the number of seconds elapsed since the last time a write was posted to that table. That write can be anything (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DDL).

That's as fast as I can get it for InnoDB

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Hi, Im using AWS RDS with MySQL 5.7, Innodb_file_per_table is enabled by default, but I can't able to get the update_time, its showing NULL;

Comment: @Bhuvanesh please run `SELECT create_time,update_time FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='...' AND table_name='...';` The table will have a create_date for sure. After its initial load, the update_time should change when you start doing new writesto the table (INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs). This  I have seen in Amazon RDS running MySQL 5.7.16.

Comment: Will it work in Aurora as well, Becuase in aurora create time is also null :(