# Log all table updates for all tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

Is there anyway I can get the last updated time of a set of tables? By last updated time, I mean not only when the table's schema changed but when any of the rows changed or even when rows were created/deleted in the given set of tables.

I tried both `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM myDb` and I only see the `create_time` which is only when table was created.

I can alternatively create triggers like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tbl1_delete AFTER DELETE ON tbl1 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_updates SET update_time = now() WHERE table_name = tbl1
END
```

But, now I have to repeat this over and over for deletes, updates, creations and schema changes. And, I want to automate this for *all* my tables!

Comment: Have you considered [the binary log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-log.html) as a source?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: This is not some one time tool I am building (else I would consider parsing the bin log). I want this for some live APIs (so something from metadat tables and/or triggers are needed)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Also, this should work for copied databases too (i.e. binlog may not be copied over or exist).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "copied" databases.

Answer (score 1):

I got some interesting news for you. You cannot use information_schema.tables because it does not track changes to InnoDB tables.

The best way to find out when a table changed is to go to the OS and get the most recent timestamp of each table. Rather than plagiarize my own posts, here are my posts where I show you how to do this

- `Sep 25, 2014` : [want to find out which databases are used in last 30 days or not](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77663/want-to-find-out-which-databases-are-used-in-last-30-days-or-not/77686#77686)
- `Jun 03, 2013` : [Is there a way to find the least recently used tables in a schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43692/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-least-recently-used-tables-in-a-schema/43697#43697)
- `Apr 04, 2013` : [How to check which tables in DB (MYSQL) updated in last 1 hour / last 1 minute?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39262/how-to-check-which-tables-in-db-mysql-updated-in-last-1-hour-last-1-minute/39271#39271)
- `Dec 21, 2011` : [Fastest way to check if InnoDB table has changed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9569/fastest-way-to-check-if-innodb-table-has-changed/9571#9571)

Give Them a Try !!!