# How to detect inactive tables?

Tags: mysql

I started working on a project whose former developer ragequited, and it left a complete mess both in the code and database. The server is using MySQL 5.5

There are a lot of tables created for backup or test purposes. For example, from all this tables, only two are really being used.

[image: tables list]

**Is there any way to check which tables weren't used in the last XX hours, to be able to safely delete them? Can I set a log for that, besides from the general log, which is really big and fills the available space too quickly?**

I cant trust names as in some cases, the table being used is the one that ends with _test or _bk.

Comment: Be sure you take a back up before you start deleting tables. And test it. Twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, using the `update_time` column from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` only works for MyISAM tables. It does not work for InnoDB.

The most effective way to get the last time a table was written is to rely on the OS. You must check the timestamp of the `.ibd` or `.MYD` files within a database folder.

I wrote earlier posts about how to do this:

- `Dec 21, 2011` : [Fastest way to check if InnoDB table has changed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9569/fastest-way-to-check-if-innodb-table-has-changed/9571#9571)
- `Apr 04, 2013` : [How to check which tables in DB (MYSQL) updated in last 1 hour / last 1 minute?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39262/how-to-check-which-tables-in-db-mysql-updated-in-last-1-hour-last-1-minute/39271#39271)
- `Jun 03, 2013` : [Is there a way to find the least recently used tables in a schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43692/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-least-recently-used-tables-in-a-schema/43697#43697)
- `Sep 25, 2014` : [want to find out which databases are used in last 30 days or not](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77663/want-to-find-out-which-databases-are-used-in-last-30-days-or-not/77686#77686)
- `Jan 16, 2015` : [How can I determine which Innodb table is being written?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89485/how-can-i-determine-which-innodb-table-is-being-written/89486#89486)

Answer (score 1):

I would ensure that MySQL query logging is enabled and then duplicate the query log. In the duplicated log I would find and replace `FROM [table_name]` one-by-one in order to determine which tables aren't being *actively* used.

Good luck! Those table names do not reflect a positive path for that developer. :-( Let me know if you need to figure out how to enable query logging in MySQL and I'll find the answer for you on that as well.

Comment: Also look for `INTO` because of `INSERT`s.  And check for other possible syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OS level stat command.
Locate the ibd file for that particular table and run the below command
**stat file_location**
If the Table is being queried by SELECT, You can find the timestamp of when it was accessed with under the Access field.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT update_time FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='yourtablename'
```

Or if you want a list of all tables, with last accessed time in order

```
SELECT table_schema ,
  table_name,
  update_time as LastAccessed
FROM information_schema.tables
GROUP BY table_schema
ORDER BY update_time ASC
```

For **tables weren't used in the last XX hours** add WHERE clause

```
WHERE update_time < 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```